# Why on Earth are there observatories on the active Mauna Loa?

Tags: volcanology, seismology, magma-plumes

Near the summit of Mauna Loa there are two observatories. Mauna Loa is an active volcano that is being watched, so why did they build observatories up there instead of building them on the dormant and slightly higher Mauna Kea? Once Mauna Loa erupts the observatories would be gone, wouldn't they? And even outside full eruptions, isn't it dangerous anyway to build an observatory near an active volcanic summit due to earthquakes, plumes and stuff?

Comment: @Weiss There are two _sky_ observatories near the summit of Mauna Loa.

Comment: *isn't it dangerous anyway to build an observatory near an active volcanic summit* — when did danger ever stop dedicated scientists from making measurements? :-)

Comment: Mauna Kea does have observatories: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauna_Kea_Observatories As for Mauna Loa, its eruptions are concentrated along the rift zones, as shown on this map for instance. https://www.usgs.gov/node/278888 As long as you build outside of these rift zones, I'd say that you are pretty safe.

Comment: @Weiss That's not quite correct. Per his autobiography, Charles David Keeling was invited to set up a CO2 monitoring station on Mauna Loa during the 1957-58 International Geophysical Year because it was a remote location and the goal was to determine a baseline level of CO2 in the global atmosphere.

Comment: @jeffronicus that sounds like good details to expand out an answer, as you sound like you have the source material that will explain the reasoning more? :)